# How to create a customizable and reusable component?

Tags: android

I designed an action bar that has several variations:

[image]

As you can see this action bar always has a header and there may be action buttons.

I understand that I can just create five action bars and use them. But I want to create one component and reuse it everywhere in my application.

For example, in ReactJS I would just create one component `ActionBar` with some properties and reuse it where I need it, such as:

```
<ActionBar
  isBackButton = true
  text = "Screen name"
  actionButton = "Add"
/>
```

or

```
<ActionBar
  isBackButton = false
  text = "Another screen name"
  actionButton = "None"
/>
```

How do I achieve this?
Or should I not get steamed up and just create five different action bars?
Or create a universal action bar with text, right and left buttons, and then dynamically customize button icons, text and onClick actions in java code?

I definitely need your advice on what to do.

Comment: What tech are you looking to do this in?  ReactNative, since your code here is all in JS?  Or standard Java/kotlin android code?  You should definitely make this a common component, not make 5 of them.

Comment: @GabeSechan Of course I'm looking for the java/kotlin android solution. I also don't like the solution through five navigation bars, which differ only partially. Could you give some example of how the common componen can be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the easiest way to do this is with a custom view.  You'd create a layout file for it:

toolbar.xml (this is simplifies to just give the basic idea, you need to fill in all the styling data:

```
  <LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/back"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon>
  </LinearLayout>
```

You'd then write a view

ToolbarView.java:

package com.example
public class ToolbarView extends View {

```
private ImageView back;
private TextView text;
private ImageView icon;
public ToolbarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.toolbar, this)
    back = findViewById(R.id.back)
    text = findViewById(R.id.text)
    //Same for all other views
}

public void setText(String text) {
   text.setText(text)
}

public void setBackEnabled(boolean enabled) {
   back.setVisibility(enabled ? VISIBLE : GONE)
}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    if(icon == null) {
        icon.setVisibility(GONE)
     }
     else {
        icon.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
        icon.setDrawable(icon)
     }
}
```

After that, you can just put `<com.example.Toolbar/>` in your other layouts and it will embed the toolbar.  You can get it via FindViewById and then call setText, setBackEnabled, etc.